# Can I hide the default "mail" tab in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, lightning

I'm only using Thunderbird for its calendar (Lightning). However, it still insists on showing the default mail `Inbox` tab, despite me having no use for it.

[image]

Is it possible to close this tab, or at least to hide the tab bar?

### EDIT

I've tried the [Lightbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/lightbird/) extension, but found it slightly too annoying to use. (Primarily because there's no way to show both month overview and calendar selection.)

Comment: Not sure if this helps: http://www.ghacks.net/2014/12/09/how-to-turn-off-tabs-in-mozilla-thunderbird/

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately, neither option seems to do anything with the calendar pane. The calendar still opens up in a new tab.